# What is like a door, but with a groove and two holes?

Tags: wood, wooden-furniture

I want to identify the following object left in the house from the previous owners. It looks like a door, but has a long groove, and two round holes. Furthermore, it has half-bullnose edge, and rounded corners. On the back there is a label, which says

```
Colour: F26
Run & N.C. Prog: 26A4-8 CNC
Slot Location:
C/O: 135016.075
Instance: SPR300720
License Plate: 135016.075
Cut Width: 29.000
Cut Length: 71.938
Smoke Developed Index Over 450

Inspections:
Routing op
Almex/Fritz
Final inspection
```

According to my measurement the width and length are indeed 29in and 72in respectively, and depth is 1in. I would like to note that our house is in the United States, but the spelling on the label says "colour", British spelling.

The pictures are below:

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Speculation**: I'm going to go with it is the panel just behind the drivers seat in a RV that makes a bed and covers the battery and the generator, as it has a [fire coating](http://www.rvbusiness.com/2014/10/vixen-develops-fire-retardant-composite-panel/) applied by either [Almex](http://www.almex-online.com/) or [Fritz Industries](http://www.fritzind.com/polymer-reactors/) for a recreational vehicle probably manufactured in Canada.

Comment: Since this is the best speculation I have heard, I accept this answer. Now, I am sure someone might need this expensively-produced piece of wood --- it would be a pity to dispose of it...

Answer (score 0):

It could be a table top,
from a desk that can be adjusted in tilt.
I have seen desks with a goove like this.

Tilting the table such that the front edge is lower than the back edge makes it hard to keep pens from rolling off the desk, so the groove serves as a place to keep them.

The rounded corners would fit well with this explanation.

In this case, the holes could be for mounting a lamp integrated with the table.